# How can I make scrapy crawl break and exit when encountering the first exception?

Tags: python, exception, scrapy

For development purposes, I would like to stop all scrapy crawling activity as soon a first exception (in a spider or a pipeline) occurs.

Any advice?

Answer (score 13):

In spider, you can just throw [CloseSpider](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html?highlight=closeSpider#closespider) exception.

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    if 'Bandwidth exceeded' in response.body:
        raise CloseSpider('bandwidth_exceeded')
```

For others (middlewares, pipeline, etc), you can manually call [close_spider](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/scraper.py#L144) as akhter mentioned.

Comment: What is the ideal place to catch spider's exceptions in scrapy ? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Since 0.11, there is [`CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-errorcount):

> An integer which specifies the maximum number of errors to receive before closing the spider. If the spider generates more than that number of errors, it will be closed with the reason closespider_errorcount. If zero (or non set), spiders won’t be closed by number of errors.

If it is set to `1`, the spider will be closed on the first exception.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem and this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

its purely depends on your business logic. but this will work for you

```
crawler.engine.close_spider(self, 'log message')
```

[Suggested Reading](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/0.12/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.contrib.closespider)

[Suggested Reading](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/0.12/topics/extensions.html#std%3asetting-CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT)

and the worst solution is

```
import sys

sys.exit("SHUT DOWN EVERYTHING!")
```