# How do I stop all spiders and the engine immediately after a condition in a pipeline is met?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

We have a system written with scrapy to crawl a few websites. There are **several spiders**, and a **few cascaded pipelines for all** items passed by all crawlers.
One of the pipeline components queries the **google servers for geocoding addresses**.
Google imposes a limit of **2500 requests per day per IP address**, and threatens to ban an IP address if it continues querying google even after google has responded with a warning message: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'.

Hence I want to know about any mechanism which I can invoke from within the pipeline that will **completely and immediately stop** all further crawling/processing of all spiders and also the main engine.

I have checked other similar questions and their answers have not worked:

- [Force my scrapy spider to stop crawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448724/force-my-scrapy-spider-to-stop-crawling)

> ```
> from scrapy.project import crawler
> crawler._signal_shutdown(9,0) #Run this if the cnxn fails.
> ```

this does not work as it takes time for the spider to stop execution and hence many more requests are made to google (which could potentially ban my IP address)

> ```
> import sys
> sys.exit("SHUT DOWN EVERYTHING!")
> ```

this one doesn't work at all; items keep getting generated and passed to the pipeline, although the log vomits sys.exit() -> exceptions.SystemExit raised (to no effect)

- [How can I make scrapy crawl break and exit when encountering the first exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524923/how-can-i-make-scrapy-crawl-break-and-exit-when-encountering-the-first-exception)

> ```
> crawler.engine.close_spider(self, 'log message')
> ```

this one has the same problem as the first case mentioned above.

I tried:

> ```
> scrapy.project.crawler.engine.stop()
> ```

To no avail

**EDIT**:
If I do in the pipeline:

> from scrapy.contrib.closespider import CloseSpider

what should I pass as the 'crawler' argument to the CloseSpider's **init**() from the scope of my pipeline?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can [raise a CloseSpider exception](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/exceptions.html#closespider) to close down a spider.
However, I don't think this will work from a pipeline.

**EDIT**: avaleske notes in the comments to this answer that he was able to raise a CloseSpider exception from a pipeline. Most wise would be to use this.

A similar situation has been described on the Scrapy Users group, [in this thread.](http://groups.google.com/group/scrapy-users/browse_thread/thread/c4e2c6edae0fcbfb)

I quote:

> To close an spider for any part of your code you should use 
>   `engine.close_spider`  method. See this extension for an usage
>   example: 
>   https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/closespider.py#L61

You could write your own extension, whilst looking at closespider.py as an example, which will shut down a spider if a certain condition has been met.

**Another** "hack" would be to set a flag on the spider in the pipeline. For example:

pipeline:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if some_flag:
        spider.close_down = True
```

spider:

```
def parse(self, response):
    if self.close_down:
        raise CloseSpider(reason='API usage exceeded')
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I figure this will close the spider as like the first example shown above but it takes time and a few items from each scheduled spider will still go through the pipeline. Which means that 100s of queries will still be made to google after the warning has been received... How do I KILL the whole thing??? If there can't be a way at all, I shall use the "hack"! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Also the CloseSpider class takes a 'crawler' argument. In my pipeline and its scope what object should be passed?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are referring to; but this doc about extensions might help: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html and the doc about pipelines: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html . I would pass the spider on to the pipeline, set the flag there, and raise a CloseSpider exception in the spider itself.

Comment: Scrapy is async, so by the time you process the response, a bunch of extra requests have already been made. Even if you stop the crawler immediately, it's still too late so don't sweat it. A couple of extra 100s wouldn't get you permanent ban from google.

Comment: Thanks for the "hack" suggestion @SjaakTrekhaak .

Comment: I was just able to raise a CloseSpider exception from within a pipeline.

Comment: @Dikei: Being async does not mean that doing 100 more scrapes after a request for stop is valid. The proper solution would be to push back items from the download queue into a to be scraped list...

Comment: FYI - I just raised a raise CloseSpider("let's close everything!") from the pipeline which did not stop my CrawlSpider's crawl (which uses a Rule() and a LinkExtractor())... using the flag to raise the exception from inside the spider did the trick though :)