# How to stop a spider from pipeline?

Tags: python, scrapy

@Sjaak Trekhaak has a 'hack' here [How do I stop all spiders and the engine immediately after a condition in a pipeline is met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699049/scrapy-how-do-i-stop-all-spiders-and-the-engine-immediately-after-a-condition-i/9699317#9699317) that can potentially stop the spiders by setting a flag in pipeline, and then call CloseSpider in the parser method. However I have the following code in pipeline (where pdate and lastseen are well defined datetime):

```
class StopSpiderPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):                                       
        if pdate < lastseen:
            spider.close_down = True
```

and in spider

```
def parse_item(self, response):                                             
    if self.close_down:                                                     
        raise CloseSpider(reason='Already scraped')
```

I got error `exceptions.AttributeError: 'SyncSpider' object has no attribute 'close_down'`, where did I get wrong? the question was actually asked by @anicake but was not responded.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your spider's `close_down` attribute create? Because it looks like it doesn't.

Try changing your check to `if "close_down" in self.__dict__:` or adding `self.close_down = False` in your spider's `__init__()` method.

Comment: thanks, turns out i have not initialized the `close_down` attribute properly: i did in the `parse_item` method, it needs to be in the class.