# How can I pause a Scrapy when I meet website blocking?

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I use scrapy to crawl user pages in 'douban.com'.
And I have 2W users in my database, I need to crawl all of these independant users' pages.

But problem is that sometimes the website would block my crawler, and if I immediate notice, I can manually shutdown the spider by Ctrl+C and restart the spider and keep going. 
In the way of simulating this behaviour I meet a lot of problems, I have two idea which is shown below:

1. pause the spider inside scrapy
   Detect 403 page since it's the sign of being blocked.
   Adding these code in parse function:

> ```
> if response.status == 403:
>     reactor.callLater(0, lambda: time.sleep(60))
> ```

This is not working, because sleep doesnt cause connections close, no matter how long it sleep, it won't be the same as manually restart the spider.

2. split the start_urls and start spiders one by one
   Since one start_url stands for one user, I split this start_urls list and put it in different spider.
   Then I start the spider by script (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/practices.html#run-from-script)
   And then I find out that twisted reactor CAN NOT be restart!

So I have no idea of how to pause the scrapy totally and automatically restart it.

Comment: maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9699317/4493674 https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html?highlight=closeSpider

Comment: @CristianOlaru In method no.2, I do raise a CloseSpider execption, but the spider can not be restart either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **errback** of scarpy requests, like this

```
    return Request(url, callback=parse, errback=error_handler)
```

and define your error handler like this

```
    def error_handler(self, failure):
        time.sleep(time_to_sleep) //time in seconds
        //after time expires, send next request
```

it will handle all response statuses other than 200.

Comment: Nope, this is not working, first, twisted won't disconnect from website, second, this will cause exception.

Comment: what kind of exception ?

Comment: Some exception about the reactor. Then I replace it by:    reactor.callLater(0, lambda: time.sleep(60)), still not working because it just sleep, not disconnect.

Comment: Have you tried creating new session after sleeping ?

Comment: What is a new session?

Comment: I think besides sleeping, you should also clear the cookies after detecting a block. The site may be tracking your spider through cookies and not just through your IP address.

Comment: Yes marven is right, with new session I meant same that you should try to delete cookies.
see this Flag in request "dont_merge_cookies=True"