# How can I stop all spiders?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Good afternoon. I have a quick question. I am using scrapy; for example, the following code:

```
class UrlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'url_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['url.com']
    start_urls = ['http://url.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for popular_link in response.xpath('//something/a/@href').extract():
            absolute_popular_link_url = response.urljoin(popular_link)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_popular_link_url,callback=self.parse_popular_link)
```

I would like to do the following: if you get a specific URL or http status code, all spiders have to stop, pause. Next create a request, next receive a response, next analyze the response, and after that start the spiders again, un-pause. If possible, can you please prove a part of the code. 
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Hello, it seems this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699049/how-do-i-stop-all-spiders-and-the-engine-immediately-after-a-condition-in-a-pipe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop all spiders and the engine immediately after a condition in a pipeline is met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699049/how-do-i-stop-all-spiders-and-the-engine-immediately-after-a-condition-in-a-pipe)