# how to force scrapy exit when there is an exception

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I wrote a crawler with **Scrapy**.

There is a function in the pipeline where I write my data to a database. I use the logging module to log runtime logs.

I found that when my string have Chinese `logging.error()` will throw an exception. But the crawler keeps running!

I know this is a minor error but if there is a critical exception I will miss it if crawler keeps running.

My question is: Is there a setting that I can force `Scrapy` stop when there is an exception?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-errorcount)

> An integer which specifies the maximum number of errors to receive
>   before closing the spider. If the spider generates more than that
>   number of errors, it will be closed with the reason
>   closespider_errorcount. If zero (or non set), spiders won’t be closed
>   by number of errors.

By default it is set to 0
`CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT = 0`
you can **change** it to **1** if you want to exit when you have the first error.

**UPDATE**

Read the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524923/how-can-i-make-scrapy-crawl-break-and-exit-when-encountering-the-first-exception),  you can also use:

```
crawler.engine.close_spider(self, 'log message')
```

for more information read :

[Close spider extension](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/0.12/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.contrib.closespider)

Comment: I missed that one! Good option.

Comment: Hi parik, I think your answers is what I want. I add following code in my spider, but it does not work, can you help me on this?: EXTENSIONS = {
   # 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
     'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider': 100,
}

CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT = 1

Comment: @scotthuang update your question and put what you tried and the error messages please

Comment: Hi parik, I fund that it actually works!. I tested it with a database exception. When I test this extension with Out Of Index exception, Scrapy stops. I will dig deeper to find out why, thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 3):

In the **process_item** function of your spider you have an instance of `spider`.

To solve your problem you could catch the **exceptions** when you insert your data, then neatly stop you spider if you catch a certain exeption like this:

```
 def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        #Insert your item here
    except YourExceptionName:
        spider.crawler.engine.close_spider(self, reason='finished')
```

Comment: This look promising, but how do you use the `YourExceptionName` in the `close_spider()`?

Comment: I don't get your question. In my exemple `YourExceptionName` stands for a custom exception, but it can be any or none. `close_spider()` is a function of the scrapy engine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to this, so I guess the question is how would a custom exception look, where is it defined?

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319675/7820534) for creating custom exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, that link clarified it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a setting that would close the crawler on any exception, but you have at least a couple of options:

- you can raise [`CloseSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html?#closespider) exception in a spider callback, maybe when you catch that exception you mention
- you can call `crawler.engine.close_spider(spider, 'some reason')` if you have a reference to the crawler and spider object, for example in an extension. See [how the `CloseSpider` extension is implemented](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/scrapy/extensions/closespider.py#L61) (it's not the same as the `CloseSpider` exception).
  You could hook this with the [`spider_error`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-error) signal for example.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the first option?