# How to Force Close a scrapy spider from a script

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have a scrapy bot that runs from a script,My problem is:After the spyder has finished crawling,the program does not end,so basically the program runs for ever until I manually shut it down,now this spyder is part of a bigger program so i cannot afford to shut it down like that as other processes havent happened.So how do i shut it down safely.
i have already surfed stackoverflow and other forums for this and i got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448724/force-my-scrapy-spider-to-stop-crawling) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524923/how-can-i-make-scrapy-crawl-break-and-exit-when-encountering-the-first-exception),the first one is totally not usable,trust me,i have tried,the second one looked promising but for some reason,`close spider` doesnt seem to close my spider when i get the signal `spider closed`

Here is the bot:

```
def pricebot(prod_name):
  class PriceBot(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pricebot'
    query = prod_name
    if query.find(' ') is not -1:
        query = query.replace(' ', '-')
    start_urls = ['http://www.shopping.com/'+query+'/products?CLT=SCH']

    def parse(self, response):

        prices_container = response.css('div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)')
        t_cont = response.css('div:nth-child(2)>h2:nth-child(1)>a:nth-child(1)>span:nth-child(1)')

        title = t_cont.xpath('@title').extract()
        price = prices_container.xpath('text()').extract()
        #Sanitise prices results
        prices = []
        for p in price:
            prices.append(p.strip('\n'))
        #Grouping Prices To Their Actual Products
        product_info = dict(zip(title, prices))
        with open('product_info.json','w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(product_info))
process = CrawlerProcess({
'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(PriceBot)
process.start()
```

After it is done,i need to do other things,call 3 other functions to be exact

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Why are you declaring that spider inside a function? Move that elsewhere and pass it an argument instead... Regarding the program not finishing I imagine if you're managing the spiders then you want to keep a reference to the main reactor and shut that down. You'll need to show the other relevant code of how you're managing spiders here...

Comment: Its in a function because it doesnt just happen,it should only happen when it is required,specifically when a user clicks a button.Passing it an argument seems great,could you elaborate on how i could do that??

Comment: That is all the code i have for the spider mate